# Batch learning in stream learning for clustering

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a "research" question:

Are there methods combining batch learning (MapReduce) in stream learning for clustering ?

Comment: This is now implemented using the Lambda Architecture !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) or [Google Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) for programming models that works in batch and stream mode.

Apache Spark has [mllib](https://spark.apache.org/mllib/) for machine learning

Comment: Thanks for the reply !
I knwo Apache Spark wich is an implementation of the MapReduce framework, and it is used to do batch learning.
There is also Spark Streaming for doing stream learning..
But my question is about methods combining batch learning in stream learning for clustering !!

Answer (score 0):

There's some really interesting Spark Stream/ MLlib integration work coming out of the Freeman Lab, performing mini-batch clustering on streams by introducing a "forgetfulness" parameter

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/01/28/introducing-streaming-k-means-in-spark-1-2.html

https://gist.github.com/freeman-lab/9672685